# Is this hideous? Copyable mutex to protect class member

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to make a class thread safe by using a mutex.

```
class Container
{
  private:
   vector<Foo> v;
   boost::mutex m;
  public:
   void add(Foo item)
   {
      m.lock();
      v.push_back(item);
      m.unlock();
   }
};
```

The problem is that `boost::mutex` is non-copyable, so this makes `Container` noncopyable.  Of course if I copy `Container` the new instance presumably doesn't need to keep the same mutex as the old one - it can have a new mutex of its own.  I could write custom copy constructors for `Container` that do this but in reality it's a complex class and I don't want to.  So how about this:

```
class CopyableMutex
{
private:
    boost::mutex m;
public:
    CopyableMutex() {}
    CopyableMutex(CopyableMutex&) {} //don't copy, just create a new one
    CopyableMutex& operator=(CopyableMutex&) {return *this;} //don't assign, keep it the same
    void lock() {m.lock();}
    void unlock() {m.unlock();}
};
```

...and then replacing `boost::mutex` in `Container` with `CopyableMutex`.

Is this a hideous thing to do?  If not then am I reinventing the wheel - is there a library class that does this already?

Comment: You can substitute 'bad idea' for 'hideous' (fsvo grammar) if you're feeling tempted to point that all C++ is hideous :)

Comment: If you only need that type in that `Container` class, just make it a private nested class (no misuse possible). Otherwise, make it clear in the *name* that it's not a copyable mutex (doesn't fulfil `CopyableMutex a; CopyableMutex b(a); assert(a == b);`), but rather a *create-new-on-invoking-copy-mutex* (which is a horrible name ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's hideous.

The correct solution to the problem is a custom copy constructor and assignment operator for your container.

If the class is "too complex" to write a custom copy constructor for, then separate the thread-safety from the container and have base class container which doesn't contain a mutex and, perhaps, a derived class "thread safe container" which contains a mutex and has a custom copy constructor and assignment op that just call through to the automatically generated base class ones.

Comment: If nothing else it's completely unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Would it be better if I called it `UniqueMutex` or `SpawningMutex` or something?

Comment: No. But perhaps I'm just being fussy about this.

Comment: Alternatively (and I think I'll do this) I could push just the vector and mutex into a contained class which I'll call ThreadSafeVector and instantiate in the complicated container class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one of the things that doing it this way invalidates is the *correct* way to use mutexes these days:

```
void func()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    // do things
  }
```

As you can not return a mutex and so there would be no way to up-scope it to where you want to use it.  The reason for the above style of usage is to prevent issues that arise when you use a lock, and then some form of unhanded exception happens prior to you unlock (ie it ensures a more reliable unlock).

I agree with other answer though, that a better way would be to just encapsulate your thread safety part and isolate it from your complex code (if possible), and then just make explicit copy constructors for that smaller class.